# Callback after X amount of async mongo queries not running.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

For some reason the callback for this is never being triggered. There are 2 messages and, correctly, the output is:

```
10
12
12
20
20
26
26
```

and then `30` should then be outputted when the callback runs but it never does.

**code**:

```
app.get("/getMessages", function (req, res) {                                        
    var JSONtoSend = [];                                                             
    getAllMessages(req.session.cur_user, function ( messages ) {                     
        console.log("10");                                                           
        async.each(messages, function (message) {                                    
            console.log("12");                                                       
            User.findById(message.senderId, function (sender) {                      
                console.log("20");                                                   
                User.findById(message.recieverId, function (reciever) {              
                    console.log("26");                                               
                    JSONtoSend.push({ content:message.content, reciever: reciever, sender: sender });
                });                                                                  
            });                                                                      
        }, function (err) { // this is the callback                                  
            if (err) {                                                               
                console.log(err);                                                    
            } else {                                                                                                                                                        
                console.log("30");                                                   
                res.json(JSONtoSend);                                                
            }                                                                        
        });                                                                          
    });                                                                              
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a callback function to your iterator. If you check the documentation ([link here](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback)), under the arguments list the second argument (the iterator) to `each` takes both message and a callback. Here's the excerpt:

> **iterator(item, callback)** - A function to apply to each item in the
>   array. The iterator is passed a callback(err) which must be called
>   once it has completed. If no error has occured, the callback should be
>   run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.

async will only run your final callback once all your iterator functions are finished - and invoking the callback to the iterator is how async keeps track of how many are complete.

Try the following:

```
app.get("/getMessages", function (req, res) {                                        
    var JSONtoSend = [];                                                             
    getAllMessages(req.session.cur_user, function ( messages ) {                     
        console.log("10");                                                           
        async.each(messages, function (message, callback) {                                    
            console.log("12");                                                       
            User.findById(message.senderId, function (sender) {                      
                console.log("20");                                                   
                User.findById(message.recieverId, function (reciever) {              
                    console.log("26");                                               
                    JSONtoSend.push({ content:message.content, reciever: reciever, sender: sender });
                    callback();
                });                                                                  
            });                                                                      
        }, function (err) { // this is the callback                                  
            if (err) {                                                               
                console.log(err);                                                    
            } else {                                                                                                                                                        
                console.log("30");                                                   
                res.json(JSONtoSend);                                                
            }                                                                        
        });                                                                          
    });                                                                              
});
```

Ideally you would also pass any possible errors to `callback()`

Comment: Ahh I understand. I was getting confused by the fact that there are 2 callbacks: one on each item and one on the entirety. Thanks!